How are moduli spaces related to geometric complexity theory?
I am interested in understanding the relationship between moduli spaces and geometric complexity theory (GCT).
Relation between moduli spaces and GCT:
How are moduli spaces related to geometric complexity theory? Are there any known connections or interactions between these fields?
Impact of breakthroughs: Hypothetically, if I were a pure mathematician whose research focused on moduli spaces, how might a breakthrough in this area influence or contribute to progress in geometric complexity theory,or in algebraic complexity theory? Are there examples where advancements in moduli spaces could lead to significant developments in GCT?
